# Internaly, how does Postgre store XML data?

Tags: xml, oracle, postgresql, storage

When Oracle stores the XML as binary data, it is stored without its XML tags. 
As we can see here: [Oracle Patent](https://www.google.com/patents/US8090731)

This mechanism allows Oracle to consume less memory when storing its XML data.

I'd like to know how does PostgreSQL store its XML data.
I found this documentation, which says that internaly Postgre will process the XML as a string through UTF-8 (if it is configured to process the data through another standard many functions do not work): [Postgre Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-xml.html)

I did not find anything that says precisely how Postgre stores its binary XML data...
As it does not verify the XML input data through its DTD ([Postgre Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-xml.html)), I think it does stores all XML tags of all documents.

Does anyone knows for sure or have more accurate references that says how Postgre stores XML data? - if it stores without its tags like Oracle, or if all XML tags of all documents are stored.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: It would be very unwise to rely on a filed patent for information about the behaviour of actual products. Patents are often filed on ideas that never make it into product, or alternatively, the design may be modified and improved or even abandoned in the course of product development.

Comment: Thanks for your observation, Michael!

Answer (score 3):

Stored as a UTF-8 string.

Excerpt from the source:

```
    /*
     * Parse the data to check if it is well-formed XML data.  Assume that
     * xml_parse will throw ERROR if not.
     */
    doc = xml_parse(result, xmloption, true, encoding);
    xmlFreeDoc(doc);

    /* Now that we know what we're dealing with, convert to server encoding */
    newstr = pg_any_to_server(str, nbytes, encoding);
```

[xml.c via github](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/2df537e43fdc432cccbe64de166ac97363cbca3c/src/backend/utils/adt/xml.c)

Basically postgres checks that the xml string is valid, and then stores it relatively as-is.

From pg_any_to_server :

```
/*
 * Convert any encoding to server encoding.
 *
 * See the notes about string conversion functions at the top of this file.
 *
 * Unlike the other string conversion functions, this will apply validation
 * even if encoding == DatabaseEncoding->encoding.  This is because this is
 * used to process data coming in from outside the database, and we never
 * want to just assume validity.
 */
char *
pg_any_to_server(const char *s, int len, int encoding)
{
```

[mbutils.c via github](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/1d25779284fe1ba08ecd57e647292a9deb241376/src/backend/utils/mb/mbutils.c)

So, it's formatted as a UTF-8 string and then stored by postgres like any string.

Comment: Note that it'll usually get stored out-of-line and compressed though, using TOAST.